# executing `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ` Oracle Statement Getting Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am NewBie to Oracle.  When I Execute Following Statement

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT * FROM DUAL;';
END;
 /
```

**I Got Error as**

> Error starting at line : 2 in command - BEGIN  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
>   'SELECT * FROM DUAL;'; END;
>
> Error report - ORA-00911:  invalid
>   character ORA-06512: at line 2
>   00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
>   *Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
>              letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
>              character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
>              any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
>              (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
>              delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
>              Reference Manual.
>   *Action:

Comment: Can u please let us know what you are trying to achieve with that statement? U can simply give `select * from dual` if u want to see some output.

Comment: Try this : BEGIN EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; END; Just remove ';' from the dymanic string.

Comment: @Crazy2crack i am trying to create a dynamic query from here ...https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/native-dynamic-sql

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar - the truncate example in that article is wrong, it should not have the semicolon inside the dynamic string either. The single-row query example is OK, and notice that is has an `into` clause. The queried data has to go somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `;` character in `'SELECT * FROM DUAL;'`.

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm):

```
execute_immediate_statement ::=
EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE dynamic_string
 { 
    INTO { define_variable [, define_variable ...] | record_name } 
  | BULK COLLECT INTO { collection_name [, collection_name ...] | :host_array_name } 
 }
   [ USING [ IN | OUT | IN OUT ] bind_argument
   [, [ IN | OUT | IN OUT ] bind_argument] ... ] [ returning_clause ] ;
```

... where `dynamic_string` is (emphasis mine):

> A string literal, variable, or expression that represents **a single SQL
>   statement** or **a PL/SQL block**. It must be of type CHAR or VARCHAR2, not
>   NCHAR or NVARCHAR2.

Since it won't accept multiple statements unless you enclose them in a single PL/SQL block, the `;` separator is not expected.

---

There's a better explanation at [Using the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Statement in PL/SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#i13130):

> When constructing a single SQL statement in a dynamic string, do not
>   include a semicolon (;) at the end inside the quotation mark. When
>   constructing a PL/SQL anonymous block, include the semicolon at the
>   end of each PL/SQL statement and at the end of the anonymous block;
>   there will be a semicolon immediately before the end of the string
>   literal, and another following the closing single quotation mark.

Comment: Or put another way, the SQL language has no semicolon.

Answer (score 4):

you can fix the error by removing `;` from the dynamic query.

```
BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
END;
 /
```

This query is not going to return any results;

`select` statement in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` without `into` clause will be ignored.

```
Declare
    v_variable number;--some variable
BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'SELECT clmn FROM tbl' into v_variable;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove ';' from the dymanic string.Try this :

```
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; 
END;
```

Comment: but it is not giving output table. am i need to supply variable for that ??

Comment: You can simply use `'Select * from dual;'` No need to give `begin` and `end`; Did u found any problem with that statement?

Comment: @Crazy2crack `Select * from dual;` gives me one row but `BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM DUAL'; 
END; ` won't

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar - [the dynamic query isn't executed if you don't have an `into` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201). Which Praveen's answer shows.